# How to change priority of specific thread (LWT) in Linux?

Tags: linux, multithreading, scheduler, renice

It's possible to see priorities and scheduling policies of all threads of a process like that:

```
ps H -o 'tid pri cls comm' PID
```

How to change the individual thread priorities from the command line?

The commands like `renice` and `chrt` seem to affect the whole process, but I'm searching the critical path among the threads. Is there maybe anything useful in `/proc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chrt

Example:

```
sudo chrt -r -p 40 1502
```

where 40 is the priority and 1502 is the TID

second column from `ps -eLo pid,tid,rtprio,ni,comm` output

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I dug into the sources of `chrt`, and it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Velkan - It doesn't do what?

Comment: @Armali, it doesn't change priority of specific thread. It changes the priority of the process.

Comment: @Velkan - The proof of the pudding is in the eating. When I try, it changes the priority of the specified TID.

Comment: @Armali, apparently changes to the kernel have unified TIDs and PIDs a bit more during these years so now it's working.